# How to stop image selecting

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm running a click event when I clicked the ball. But sometime click doesn't work, I'm selecting image accidently and it stops click event..

I tried to remove selectable property with below css properties, but doesn't work

```
pointer-events: none; // it stops click event, selecting continue
user-select: none;  // it doesn't change anything
```

element and css

```
#ball {
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
}

<img id="ball" src="images/ball.png"/>
```

How can I make it image not selectable ?

Comment: You might consider show more of the code for context.

Comment: You could try to make image a background image.

Comment: Are you using jQuery Ui?

Comment: @Ananth No I'm not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using CSS only.

The following code should help you to achieve the desired results.

```css
#ball {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img id="ball" src="images/ball.png">
```

Working in the above snippet.